# GCM for Android- unable to unsubscribe from a topic

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM- topic based messaging in an Android app I'm developing.
It's working fine, but I would like to give users the option to stop receiving the push messages.
Of course, disabling notifications from the app settings will work, but I want to let users disable/enable push messages from the app.

So I'm using the following to try and unsubscribe from the topic(on click of a button) :

```
GcmPubSub pubSub =  GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
try{pubSub.unsubscribe(MyRegistrationToken,"MyTopic");}                    
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Also ensuring that the background service that subscribes to the topic will not run while unsubscribed. However, it doesn't seem to be working as I'm still receiving the push messages after unsubscribing with the above code. Am I doing anything wrong or missing something?

I have found a work around(just not displaying the notification while unsubscribed), but would like to actually unsubscribe so that the server stops sending the push messages to the device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Using 8.3.0 now, without any difference.Let me post the full code of me subscribing & unsubscribing, if that'll help you shed some light:
Using an intent-service to subscribe, as follows:

```
try {
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/MyTopic", null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unsubscribing from an activity on click of a button as follows:

```
try {
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    pubSub.unsubscribe(token, "/topics/MyTopic");           
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully unsubscribed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();          
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to unsubscribe..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

The button also exits the activity. I even tried saving the registeration token(in shared preferences) while registering and using it to unsubscribe in case generating a new instanceID led to the problem. But no matter what, onclick of the button, it's going to the catch block.
Once the button to unsubscribe is clicked, ensuring that the registaeration intent will not work so I can't see how it can re-register. It doesn't seem to be unsubscribing successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to a topic you specify the topic as "/topics/TOPIC_NAME", you should use the same format when unsubscribing so try:

```
GcmPubSub pubSub =  GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
try{pubSub.unsubscribe(MyRegistrationToken,"/topics/MyTopic");}                    
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Both subscribe and unsubscribe should be called off the UI thread, for example in an intent service.

Comment: try{pubSub.unsubscribe(MyRegistrationToken,"/topics/MyTopic");}

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to reproduce this, either you are re-subscribing to the topic somewhere or the unsubscribe is not working as expected on your device/emulator. I can only suggest that you should be sure to use the latest version of Google Play Services play-services-gcm:8.3.0

Comment: Edited post with more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the InstanceID from a new thread seems to have done the trick:

```
final InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                instanceID.deleteInstanceID(); }
             catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); } } });
    thread.start();
```

And the messages stopped.